# Hibiscus colour change?

Tags: flowers

A new colour?

[image]

From my hibiscus. 4 years white flowers, this is the first time I have put it outside during the summer.

Answer (score 2):

> So, depending on its variety, your hibiscus changed color because of some combination of temperature, sunlight, nutrition, or pH has taken place. Can gardeners control this hibiscus color change? Yes, indirectly – by controlling the plant’s environment: shade or sun, good fertility, and protection from hot or cold weather.

From [Can Hibiscus Change Color: Reasons For Hibiscus Turning A Different Color](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/flowers/hibiscus/hibiscus-turning-different-color.htm)

Comment: How exciting a morphing!